# Updating several records in a database with increasing value

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update several records in a table, and am hoping to accomplish it in one query.

I have a php array of id's for a few of the records in my table. The array is in a specific order, and I need to update a value for each id with the position/key that the id is in the array. I could easily loop through each value in the array and run a query for each record that needs to be updated, but I am looking for a way to possibly update each record in one query.

The following will give me the desired result, but I am looking for a **one query solution**.

```
$ID = array('3','2','6','5','9');
for($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++){
    $q = "UPDATE table SET blah = ".$i." WHERE id = ".$ID[$i];
    mysql_query($q) or die();   
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, mostly because your condition where every update has to be with a different row id.

Comment: By the way... Java ORM library, Hibernate, has a feature that you can change few objects, then flush the changes to DB - and it creates a single `INSERT` for all these changes.

Comment: @Ondra Žižka: that's nice, and it wouldn't be no problem at all for a SQL query doing an `INSERT`. However, we are talking about `UPDATE`s. A very different kind of breed, unless we would abuse `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 queries:

First only needed in case you have used `@var` already.

```
SET @var := -1;
```

And then (note `FIND_IN_SET` wants a comma-separated *string*):

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET blah = @var := @var +1
WHERE id IN (3,2,6,5,9)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id,'3,2,6,5,9');
```

If you have an array with key=>postition pairs, this could be used:

```
$array = array(2 => 40,3 => 12,5 => 8,6 => 9,9 =>13129);
mysql_query("
   UPDATE bla
   SET blah = ELT(
     FIELD(id,".implode(',',array_keys($array))."),
      ".implode(',',$array).")
   WHERE id IN (".implode(',',array_keys($array)).")");
```

Comment: IIRC, the `@var := @var +1` expression is not  guaranteed by MySQL to be evaluated for every row, or in order win which rows are returned. This behavior may change in future versions. (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: Have you got a link about that? Because I've used this for years without any problems.

Comment: I'm assuming @var is a reference variable. I've never used those with php and mysql and can't seem to get it to work. Any tips/places I can look to learn more?

Comment: Here ya go: [user defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html)

Answer (score 1):

A big long ugly if or case statement would do the trick:

```
UPDATE ...
SET blah = IF(id=3,1,IF(id=2, 2, IF(id=6,3, IF....))))
WHERE id IN (3,2,6,....)
```

it'd quickly become unmanageable, but it would accomplish things in a single query. A slightly cleaner, more portable alternative:

```
UPDATE
SET blah = CASE id WHEN 3 THEN 1 WHEN 2 THEN 2 WHEN 6 THEN 3 .... END CASE
WHERE id in (3,2,6,...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (idCol, valCol) VALUES (id1, value1),(id2, value2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  idCol = VALUE(idCol),
  valCol = VALUE(valCol)
```

You could also use a stored procedure, passing it a string of the ID's:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateItems( firstNum INT NOT NULL, ids TEXT NOT NULL) BEGIN
   @id := ... #  Some expression to get the first ID.
   WHILE id != "" DO
      SET ids := ... #  Some expression to get the rest of the string.
      UPDATE table SET blah = firstNum WHERE id = @id;
      SET firstNum = firstNum +1;
      @id := ... ;
   END;
END $$
```

Also, there was one trick with `LAST_INSERT_ID()` - if you call it with a param, like `LAST_INSERT_ID( 123 )`, successive call to `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will give you `123`.
Could be used together with `@variables` to achieve that goal.

You might get some inspiration here: http://ondra.zizka.cz/stranky/programovani/sql/mysql_stored_procedures.texy

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible in this way ...Well, it's possible but I'd suggest you not to do it, 5 queries aren't horrors

Comment: I only used 5 as an example. I'm looking at closer to about 20 queries once all said and done... any suggestions as to a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = "UPDATE table SET blah = ".$i." WHERE id in ('3','2','6','5','9')";
```

Comment: Almost what I need, but $i needs to be increased for each value.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, misunderstood the problem... let me see if I can come up with another solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about performance, you should take a look at using prepared statements and transactions.

There is most likely a solution to doing this in one single query, but it would most likely get really messy.

Answer (score 0):

your better of using foreach then you don't have to set a $i limit.
i think its quick to do it this way

```
$id = array('3','2','6','5','9');
$i=0;

 foreach ($id as $v){

    $q = "UPDATE table SET blah = ".$i++." WHERE id = '$v'";
    mysql_query($q) or die();   

 }
```